# Gradle DockerExecContainer cant source bash script from task

Tags: bash, docker, gradle

I am trying to create a test task in gradle using build.gradle and the [plugin from bmuschko](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/) for handling docker. After starting the docker container from the image I need to source a bash script with *DockerExecContainer* and afterwards check if it works. Somehow I can't source it from the gradle task. If I use `docker run -it --rm 83d7ba3dc19b /bin/bash` and use `. env.sh` or `source env.sh` inside the container it works. Here are my gradle tasks:

```groovy
tasks.register("createTestContainer", DockerCreateContainer) {
    targetImageId "83d7ba3dc19b"
    hostConfig.portBindings = ["8080:8080"]
    hostConfig.autoRemove = true
}

tasks.register("startTestContainer", DockerStartContainer) {
    dependsOn "createTestContainer"
    containerId = tasks.named("createTestContainer").get().containerId
}

tasks.register("runTest", DockerExecContainer) {
    dependsOn "startTestContainer"
    finalizedBy "stopTestContainer"

    containerId = tasks.named("createTestContainer").get().containerId
    withCommand(['source', "/opt/example/env.sh"])
    //withCommand(['.', "/opt/example/env.sh"])

    onNext { frame ->
        def consoleOut = new String(frame.payload, "UTF-8")
        println("Got results: ${consoleOut}")
    }
}

tasks.register("stopTestContainer", DockerStopContainer) {
    dependsOn "startTestContainer"
    mustRunAfter(
        "runTest",
    )
    containerId = tasks.named("createTestContainer").get().containerId
}
```

Here is the error code if I run `gradle runTest`:

```
> Task :runTest
Executing on container with ID 'd30ff3f40e646cf7f175146746a9e22c7b0b45c765e815c173c7d3c6cb470123'.
Got results: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "source": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Does someone know what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.